# log4j2 DynamicThresholdFilter not picking up property value

Tags: log4j2

Trying to set different printing levels for console and file.

Goal is: when **debug=true**, print **debug level** (console & file), else only print **error level** (console).

Change it *programatically* like this:

```
 @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
       ThreadContext.put("debugMode", "true");
   }
```

This is my log4j2 configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
   <Properties>
       <Property name="logPath">${sys:catalina.home}</Property>
       <Property name="rollingFileName">vsTenant</Property>
   </Properties>

   <Appenders>                                   
       <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">  
           <filters>>   
                <DynamicThresholdFilter key="debugMode" defaultThreshold="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL">
                   <KeyValuePair key="true" value="DEBUG"/>    
                   <KeyValuePair key="false" value="ERROR"/>       
               </DynamicThresholdFilter>              
           </filters>                         
           <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level [vsTenant] %logger{36} - %msg\n%n" />
       </Console>                

       <RollingFile name="rollingFile" fileName="${logPath}/logs/vsTenant.log" filePattern="${logPath}/logs/vsTenant_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log">            
          <filters>>   
                <DynamicThresholdFilter key="debugMode" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY">
                   <KeyValuePair key="true" value="DEBUG"/>                      
               </DynamicThresholdFilter>              
           </filters>               
          <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level [vsTenant] %logger{36} - %msg\n%n" />
           <Policies>               
               <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB" />              
           </Policies>            
           <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>            
       </RollingFile>       
   </Appenders>

   <Loggers>
       <Root level="ERROR" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="console" /> 
           <AppenderRef ref="rollingFile" />
       </Root>
   </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

It is always printing ERROR level. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You were close, only a few small changes are needed to achieve what you want.

1. Change the first `onMismatch` from `NEUTRAL` to `DENY`
2. Add a second `KeyValuePair` to the second filter: `<KeyValuePair key="false" value="OFF"/>`
3. Change the `Root` log level from `ERROR` to `TRACE`

Here's the modified configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
   <Properties>
       <Property name="logPath">${sys:catalina.home}</Property>
       <Property name="rollingFileName">vsTenant</Property>
   </Properties>

   <Appenders>                                   
       <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">  
           <filters>
                <DynamicThresholdFilter key="debugMode" defaultThreshold="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY">
                   <KeyValuePair key="true" value="DEBUG"/>    
                   <KeyValuePair key="false" value="ERROR"/>       
               </DynamicThresholdFilter>              
           </filters>                         
           <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level [vsTenant] %logger{36} - %msg\n%n" />
       </Console>                

       <RollingFile name="rollingFile" fileName="${logPath}/logs/vsTenant.log" filePattern="${logPath}/logs/vsTenant_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log">            
          <filters> 
                <DynamicThresholdFilter key="debugMode" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY">
                   <KeyValuePair key="true" value="DEBUG"/> 
                   <KeyValuePair key="false" value="OFF"/>                    
               </DynamicThresholdFilter>              
           </filters>               
          <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level [vsTenant] %logger{36} - %msg\n%n" />
           <Policies>               
               <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB" />              
           </Policies>            
           <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>            
       </RollingFile>       
   </Appenders>

   <Loggers>
       <Root level="TRACE" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="console" /> 
           <AppenderRef ref="rollingFile" />
       </Root>
   </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here is some java code to test it with:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();   

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ThreadContext.put("debugMode", "false");
        log.info("Info should not show anywhere");
        log.debug("This shouldn't show anywhere");

        ThreadContext.put("debugMode", "true");
        log.debug("This should show in the log and console");
        log.info("This should also show in both");

        ThreadContext.put("debugMode", "false");
        log.info("This should not show anywhere");
        log.error("This error should show only in console.");
    }
}
```

Running the above will output the following to console:

```
21:16:40.716 [main] DEBUG [vsTenant] example.SomeClass - This should show in the log and console

21:16:40.718 [main] INFO  [vsTenant] example.SomeClass - This should also show in both

21:16:40.718 [main] ERROR [vsTenant] example.SomeClass - This error should show only in console.
```

and output the following to the log file:

```
21:16:40.716 [main] DEBUG [vsTenant] example.SomeClass - This should show in the log and console

21:16:40.718 [main] INFO  [vsTenant] example.SomeClass - This should also show in both
```

Comment: it is working for debugMode=true, however, false is still printing debug level for both file and console :(

Comment: @superflyingcrap please see the code I added. Are you setting the `debugMode` to `false` initially as I am in the example because you need to have one of the expected values in order for the filter to work.

Comment: I tried your example, it's working! We are however set it in our Servlet class like this: `@Override
 public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
  ThreadContext.put("debugMode", "false");
 }`

But, we have so many class, do we need to set it in every class?

Comment: If the key, in your case "debugMode" has no value (it is null) then the default threshold will not apply and neither will any of your `KeyValuePair` settings. This will not generate the desired result. So you must ensure that "debugMode" is not null before you do any logging. [ThreadContext](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html) is associated with each thread so as long as you set "debugMode" at each **entry point** into your application you should be fine.

Comment: If setting the "debugMode" at each entry point is not feasible for you then I suggest taking a different approach such as making use of [RoutingAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) similar to an [example on the log4j2 FAQ page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#separate_log_files).